# UICollectionView adding action in Header (Swift)

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, uisegmentedcontrol

I have a collectionView and a header for that collection view. I've added a UISegmentControl in my header and now I'm trying to pass the selectedSegmentIndex value to main collectionView, So i'm trying to addTarget for that segment in my UICollectionViewController but its not returning anything, here is my code

```
 override func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, atIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

        let headerView = self.collectionView?.dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind(UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: "header", forIndexPath: indexPath) as collectionHeaderView
        headerView.controlSegment.userInteractionEnabled = true
        headerView.controlSegment.addTarget(self, action: "segmentAction:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
        return headerView
    }

    func segmentAction(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
        println(sender.selectedSegmentIndex)
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct control event would be `.ValueChanged`:

```
headerView.controlSegment.addTarget(self, 
        action: Selector("segmentAction:"), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
```